# How to revoke this command?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, permissions, ssh

OS:Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

I just made one simple mistake I don't know what i type even because now i'm unable to track the command history.

I think i might used $chmod go+wx /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp

Here is the problem set:

Due to the past action the result is... changed file system to 777:

[image: Changed filesystem user from root to 777]

Now i can't login as root or normal user as well.

Can anyone help me to get back my server to normal stage?

Here is the console output when i tried to use ssh login

```
$ssh user@ip
output : ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried to do like this as well.

```
$ssh -v user@ip
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kiran/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: try `sudo chown -R root /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp`

Comment: Is it only your / directory with 777 permissions? If it is, I'd guess that your guess is partly correct - that you started to enter `chmod go+wx /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp` but pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> before the `tmp/tomcat...` part. Check permissions in a sub-directory of /, and add that to your question. You say you're "unable to track the command history" - what happens when you try the `history` command?